# kendo ui - tree, cannot update main node

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, angular-kendo

I am using angular + kendo ui. I have created a tree and added first node as dummy

```
$scope.treeData = kendo.observableHierarchy({
         data: [{ text: "" ,items: [] }]
    });
```

after that when I have the right data , I want to place the right data

```
function init() {
        var query = CSensorGroupRepositoryService.getQueyObject().where("ParentID", "==", 0); // groups with no parent
        CSensorGroupRepositoryService.getEntitiesByQuery(query).then(function (results) {
            var parent = { text: results[0].GroupName, items: [] };

            buildTreeHierarchy(results[0], parent);
            $scope.treeData[0].text = results[0].GroupName;

        });
    }
```

how ever in the view - the text is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ObservableObject.set`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/observableobject#methods-set) so the change event is triggered and your widget updates its view:

```
$scope.treeData[0].set("text", results[0].GroupName);
```

Comment: for items, you can try something like this: `$scope.treeData[0].children.data([{ text: "new item" }]);`